# create multiple columns from 1 column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multiple-columns

I am trying to duplicate a column multiple time from a df such as

```
df.head()

                      close
date                       
2015-09-23 17:00:00  1.3324
2015-09-23 17:01:00  1.3325
2015-09-23 17:02:00  1.3323
2015-09-23 17:03:00  1.3323
2015-09-23 17:04:00  1.3323
```

from a certain list of name, I want to duplicate that colum as many time as there is name in my list:

```
list =['a','b','c']
```

and get

```
  df.head()

                      close    a     b      c
date                       
2015-09-23 17:00:00  1.3324 1.3324 1.3324 1.3324
2015-09-23 17:01:00  1.3325 1.3325 1.3325 1.3325
2015-09-23 17:02:00  1.3323 1.3323 1.3323 1.3323
2015-09-23 17:03:00  1.3323 1.3323 1.3323 1.3323
2015-09-23 17:04:00  1.3323 1.3323 1.3323 1.3323
```

I tried

```
df[list] = df
```

but columns must be same length as key. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way would be to iterate through your list and create a new column for each key (side note: you should probably avoid using `list` as the name of a variable, since you'll overwrite the native `list`):

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
for k in keys:
    df[k] = df['close']
```

If you want to do it in one line, without a loop, you could do the following:

```
keys = ['a','b','c']
df = df.join(pd.concat([df.close]*len(keys), keys=keys))
```

Moving outwards from the middle, `[df.close]*len(keys)` creates a list with as many copies of the original dataframe column as there are keys in your list.  These are then combined into one dataframe using `pd.concat()`, with the column names being set with your list (`keys=keys`).  Now that you have a dataframe with your duplicate columns, you can add it to the original dataframe using `df.join()`.

Comment: ya this work just fine thanks! I am trying to stay away from loop but I guess i'll use this :) about list : taking good note thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
li = ['a','b','c']

df1 = pd.concat([df['close']]*(len(li)+1), axis=1, keys=['close'] + li)
print (df1)
                      close       a       b       c
date                                               
2015-09-23 17:00:00  1.3324  1.3324  1.3324  1.3324
2015-09-23 17:01:00  1.3325  1.3325  1.3325  1.3325
2015-09-23 17:02:00  1.3323  1.3323  1.3323  1.3323
2015-09-23 17:03:00  1.3323  1.3323  1.3323  1.3323
2015-09-23 17:04:00  1.3323  1.3323  1.3323  1.3323
```